# Compilation error requiring install Microsoft.Bcl.Build. How to install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build on a unit test project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, .net-4.0, nuget-package, microsoft.bcl

I have a vs2013 solution with 2 projects in NET 4.0, let's say project A and project B. Project B has a reference to project A. When I compile project B I get a compilation error saying:

```
All projects referencing ProjectA.csproj must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317569.
```

To install nuget package on project B I select project B in solution explorer, then I open a nuget console and type below command:

> Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Build -Version 1.0.21

but it seems it is not installing it on project B. What am I doing wrong?